# Cant do bulk insert into PGadmin

Tags: python, orm, psycopg2, pgadmin

I have this code in my ORM

```
    def insert(self, rows: dict):
        field_names = rows.keys()
        assert all(row.keys() == field_names for row in rows)  # confirm that all rows have the same fields

        fields_format = ", ".join(field_names)
        values_placeholder_format = ", ".join([f'({", ".join(["%s"] * len(field_names))})'] * len(
            rows))  

        query = f"INSERT INTO {self.model_class.table_name} ({fields_format}) " \
                f"VALUES {values_placeholder_format}"

        params = list()
        for row in rows:
            row_values = [row[field_name] for field_name in field_names]
            params += row_values


        self._execute_query(query, params)
```

And i have my dict,which i need to insert into my DB, but when i do this,i have an error **'str' object has no attribute 'keys'**. This is my dict

```
{'AED': 3.67304, 'AFN': 88.494599, 'ALL': 116.95, 'AMD': 405.10373, 'ANG': 1.808175, 'AOA': 431.25095, 'ARS': 142.87505, 'AUD': 1.486241, 'AWG': 1.8, 'AZN': 1.7, 'BAM': 1.960624, 'BBD': 2}
```

Comment: I think it is because `rows` is a dictionary and has keys, while `row` correspond to 1 element in the disctionary which does not have keys. You could try simply `all(rows.keys() == field_names)`

Comment: @RémyPétremand no, it isnt, i thought that problem is my field names,probably, because i have currency_name and currency_value in my DB,and trying to insert dict with "AED" not currency_value, mb list comprehension will help me

Comment: Would this solve the issue: `assert all(row_key == field_names for row_key in rows.keys())`

Comment: @RémyPétremand returning this - assert all(row_key == field_names for row_key in rows.keys())
AssertionError